# Obtain country from wikidata item using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get the country of a Wikidata item using SPARQL. I am quite new and I am not able to obtain only the property country (P17) and its label.

I used this example and I am able to obtain all properties. [Link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20?wdLabel%20?ooLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20VALUES%20(?s)%20%7B(wd:Q1492)%7D%0A%20?s%20?wdt%20?o%20.%0A%20?wd%20wikibase:directClaim%20?wdt%20.%0A%20?wd%20rdfs:label%20?wdLabel%20.%0A%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20?o%20rdfs:label%20?oLabel%20.%0A%20FILTER%20(lang(?oLabel)%20=%20%22en%22)%0A%20%7D%0A%20FILTER%20(lang(?wdLabel)%20=%20%22en%22)%0A%20BIND%20(COALESCE(?oLabel,%20?o)%20AS%20?ooLabel)%0A%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20xsd:integer(STRAFTER(STR(?wd),%20%22http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P%22))).

In this case using the output of a previous query, for example, I get the item Q1492 corresponding to Barcelona. How can I obtain its country, Spain?

Comment: spoiler: `SELECT ?country
WHERE {
 wd:Q1492 wdt:P17 ?country
 }` is the most basic query to achieve what you want

Comment: not sure why my first comment was deleted, but fair enough SO mods

Comment: @AKSW Yeah! That's exactly it but is there a way to obtain the name directly and not the wikidata ID?

Comment: Of course: `SELECT ?countryLabel WHERE { wd:Q1492 wdt:P17 ?country 
                      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }}` - or with standard SPARQL to understand what the label service does: `SELECT ?countryLabel WHERE { wd:Q1492 wdt:P17 ?country. 
                            ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel 
                                     filter(lang(?countryLabel) = "en")
                      }`